# Pandas: speeding up groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Lets assume the dataframe:

```
df=
col_1 col_2 col3 
id1   val1  1    
id2   val1  4    
id3   val1  5    
id4   val1  7    
id1   val2  3    
id2   val2  2    
id3   val2  8    
id4   val2  4
```

for each row, i need to add a column with the sum of `col3` from all other rows where

`col2 == row[col2] AND col1 != row[col1]`

so i should get:

```
df=
col_1 col_2 col3 col4
id1   val1  1    16
id2   val1  4    13
id3   val1  5    12
id4   val1  7    10
id1   val2  3    14
id2   val2  2    15
id3   val2  8    9
id4   val2  4    13
```

I did it using apply and something like

```
def getVal(row, df):
    return df[(df[col1] != row[col1]) & (df[col2] == row[col2])][col3].sum()

df[col4] = df.apply(lambda x: getVal(x, df), axis = 1)
```

but since my `df` has `>1000000` rows, it takes forever!!!
Is there a better/faster way?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What about pre-calculating the sums only once, storing them in a nested list, and then subtracting `col3` to the specific sum?

Answer (score 2):

Use `groupby` with `transform` for this one-liner no merges:

```
df['col4'] = df.groupby('col_2')['col3'].transform('sum') - df['col3']
```

Output:

```
  col_1 col_2  col3  col4
0   id1  val1     1    16
1   id2  val1     4    13
2   id3  val1     5    12
3   id4  val1     7    10
4   id1  val2     3    14
5   id2  val2     2    15
6   id3  val2     8     9
7   id4  val2     4    13
```

Answer (score 0):

[@Roberto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2962364/roberto) pointed me to the right direction:

```
df2 = df.groupby([col2])[col3].sum().reset_index().rename(columns = {col3:'extra_col'})
df = pd.merge(df, df2, on = [col2], how = 'left')
df[col4] = df[extra_col] - df[col3]
```